# How do i force VBA to add a row itself and used that row to print the output

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add some code in which the code add an empty row at B29 itself rather then i add myself  without disturbing the Alignement of **CRONS** in B29. I know after adding empty row at B29 **CRONS** will no more at B29 but it doesn't matter what matter is the alignment for for rest of the sheet. The picture is from sheet1 where I have to add the empty row and print the output (In line14).

[image]

The code I wrote is based on 2 sheets

```
1. Sub Energy_consumption_per_cubic()
2. Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
3. Dim check1 As Boolean, check12 As Boolean, motor_power As Boolean, flow As Boolean

4. Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
5. Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

6. check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
7. check12 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 5").Value = xlOn
8. motor_power = s1.Range("B25").Value = "Motor Power"
9. flow = s1.Range("B26").Value = "Flow(from fill level)"


10. If ((check1 And check12) Or _
11.     (check1 And motor_power) Or _
12.     (flow And check12) Or _
13.     (flow And motor_power)) Then
14.        s1.Range("B29").Value = "Energy consumption per cubic"
15. Else
16.     s1.Range("B29").Value = "-"
17. End If

18. End Sub
```

Comment: Are the used check boxes of type ActiveX and is their `FormatControl` property `Object Positioning` set to `Move but don't size with cells`? If not, it must be so...

Comment: checkboxes are of activeX, the rest i dont know what you want to know as i am new to VBA :(

Comment: Right click on the check box, when in Design mode, choose `Format Control`, then `Properties` and see what is checked in `Object Positioning`. If as I suggested, it should be OK to insert a row and all check boxes below will jump down with the cells they are on...

Comment: it is checked on "Move but don't size with cells"

Comment: Then, why having a problem inserting a row? What (unpleasant) happens when you do it?

Comment: Does `rows(range("A1:A100").find("Crons")).insert` not automatically shift the content down, leaving the formatting in the below (and above) rows the same?

Comment: @FaneDuru it just print the output in front of CRONS in B29.

Comment: @Cyril thanks for the response, but to be honest i did not get your point :(

Comment: I cannot get you... Your code does not insert any row. Then, what do you mean by "I have to add the empty row and print the output (In line14)"? If you insert a row below "line 14", how will it be influenced? Your code only change the existing value of "B29" with something else. I think it's time to **better** explain **in words** what you try accomplishing...

Comment: @FaneDuru I just want to write a code in which the CRON row goes automatically on position B30 and my output "Energy consumption per cubic" comes at B29.

Comment: This is something else, I am afraid... I will adapt your code and post it as an answer...

Comment: Please, test the updated code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: It is good to learn that better focusing on clearly explaining **what you want** against what you have, will be easier for us to understand your need...

Comment: @wasifahmed my suggestion is essentially what Fane did in the answer, where `cellCR` finds the cell with "Crons", then in that entire row it inserts, which shifts cells down.  Splitting the `find()` into a separate range allows for the `If` statement to verify that the value is `not nothing` before working, which prevents errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code. It searches for string "Crons" in column "A:A" and inserts a row above it (if found):

```
Sub Energy_consumption_per_cubic()
 Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, cellCr As Range
 Dim check1 As Boolean, check12 As Boolean, motor_power As Boolean, flow As Boolean

 Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

 check1 = s2.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").value = xlOn
 check12 = s2.CheckBoxes("Check Box 5").value = xlOn
 motor_power = s1.Range("B25").value = "Motor Power"
 flow = s1.Range("B26").value = "Flow(from fill level)"

 Set cellCr = s1.Range("A1:A" & s1.Range("A" & s1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Find("Crons")
     If Not cellCr Is Nothing Then 'if a cell in A:A having "Crons" value exists:
        s1.rows(cellCr.row).Insert 'insert a row above it
        If ((check1 And check12) Or _
                (check1 And motor_power) Or _
                (flow And check12) Or _
                (flow And motor_power)) Then
            s1.Range("B29").value = "Energy consumption per cubic"
        Else
           s1.Range("B29").value = "-"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not found ""Crons"" in A:A...": Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```